# Проиграть мелодию звонящему

Tags: android

Можно ли как-то при телефонном разговоре, по нажатию кнопки в моём приложении, чтобы проигралась какая либо мелодия, и чтобы её услышал человек с которым ведётся беседа? 
(просто громко проиграть мелодию не вариант)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент это невозможно.

Это описано в официальной документации

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

> Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output
>   device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth
>   headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during
>   a call.

**Перевод:**

> Замечание: Вы можете проигрывать аудио файлы только в стандартные 
>   устройства вывода. На данный момент это динамики и Bluetooth гарнитура.
>   Вы не можете проигрывать звуковые файлы в телефонном разговоре.